# Keyboard-focus on Texbox in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I made a login form on Flex and set the focus on the first textbox. 
The textbox is highlighted, but I have to click on it in order to be able to write inside it.
How can I make it takes keyboard input directly without clicking? I mean directly after loading the page.

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[   
        private function init():void {
            trace("Authentication View init");
            ExternalInterface.call('function browserFocus(){document.getElementById(\'${application}\').focus();}');
            this.txtUsername.setFocus();
            this.txtUsername.setFocus();
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<s:Panel x="353" y="164" width="250" height="200">
    <s:TextInput id="txtUsername" x="103" y="49" focusEnabled="true"/>
    <s:TextInput x="103" y="79"/>
    <s:Label x="26" y="49" text="Username"/>
    <s:Label x="26" y="79" text="Password"/>
</s:Panel>
```

Comment: Use the setFocus method of the FocusManager Class: [Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/FocusManager.html). So in your case `focusmanager.setfocus(txtUsername)`

Comment: It says :Multiple markers at this line:
-Access of undefined property focusmanager
-1 changed line

Comment: "Access of undefined property focusmanager"

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. `focusManager` is the name of the property.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I am facing the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Set focus like following inside `init()` function.

```
txtUsername.setFocus();
```

And Apply following code inside **html-template/index.template.html.** before HTML end tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function onFlexInitialized()
        {
            //alert("onFlexInitialized");

            <!-- Force the browser to set flex app with focus -->
            document.getElementById("${application}").focus();
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is the issue. But I couldn't set the focus onto the Flas application itself.

Comment: @Subaiesarah Have you set given script inside. `html-template/index.template.html` ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding this inside the body tag in html-template/index.template.html.

```
onLoad="window.document.Login.focus();"
```

and it worked corrctly. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Index-template:

> ```
> <div id="flashContent">    
>   <script type="text/javascript"> 
>
>       function setFocus(){
>           window.document.getElementById("APPNAME").focus();
>           $('#txtUsername').focus();
>           $('#txtUsername').focusEnables=true;
>       } 
>
>   </script>  
> </div>
> ```

Application:

> ```
> private function init():void{
>   if (ExternalInterface.available) {
>       ExternalInterface.call('setFocus');
>   } 
> }
> ```